# Anchor removed from DIV after Quick Edit is used

Tags: html, quick-edit

We have a page we normally edit in basic edit mode. There are a group of DIVs with link tags on them. When a non-technical editor/staffer goes into quick-edit mode for that page, the links are removed from the DIV. Why? Is this normal WP behaviour?

Example

```
<a href="http://example.com"><div><img src="./image.png></div></a>
```

After Quick Edit

```
<div><img src="./image.png"></div>
```

The current workaround is to not use quick-edit for pages with anchored images.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe it's because of the hierarchy behind base HTML.  div's are block elements, and a's are inline. So, a's by default don't wrap div tags.  If you managed to use a span in its place, or changed the order to go div > a > img, it would probably keep it.